# TextInputLayout drawables not fitting when android:background attribute is set on theme

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I have a simple TextInputLayout. It works perfect when I don't set android:background attribute on my theme style, but when I set it, any drawable I try is not fitting inside of TextInputLayout:
[image of not fitting drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpbxQ.png)

Note that, the error happens with every drawable (startIconDrawable, passwordToggleDrawable etc.)

My TextInputLayout code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutSearchText"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_6sdp"
    android:hint="@string/SongName"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_cancel"
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/fit_turquoise"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/fit_white"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

There shouldn't be any error on TextInputLayout XML, since it works perfectly when the android:background attribute is not set on the theme style.

And here is how I set the attribute on my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/fit_bg_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/fit_turquoise</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/fit_turquoise</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/fit_status_bar_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ubuntu_medium</item>
    <item name="popupMenuBackground">@color/fit_bg_blue</item>
</style>
```

Why are they not working together? What am I supposed to do if I want to use both the attribute and the TextInputLayout with an endIconDrawable?

Comment: `android:background` is not an attribute that you want to set in your theme. That will put that background on every single `View`, by default, even those `View`s that shouldn't have backgrounds, like the `ImageView`s that are being used internally for those icons.

Comment: @MikeM. So, do you mean the drawables of TextInputLayout happen to have unintended background because of the background attribute I set on the theme?

Comment: Not the drawables themselves, but the `ImageView`s that are created internally by `TextInputLayout` to display those drawables. (They're actually custom library `ImageView`s, but same thing applies.) That `android:background` in your theme is causing those `ImageView`s to have that background set on them by default, and nothing else is going to change that back, 'cause it's assumed that they have no backgrounds to begin with. Follow me?

Comment: @MikeM. I get it now, it is great to learn that. Thanks. From now on, I will use `android:background` on my layouts instead.